# UnknownNode ao carregar XML em classe

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, classes

Recebo o seguinte XML de um banco (dados modificados, mas a estrutura é esta mesmo)

```
<registro>
  <header>
    <codUsuario>XXX</codUsuario>
    <codLojista>999</codLojista>
  </header>
  <parametros>
    <consulta>XXX</consulta>
  </parametros>
  <ROWS>
    <ROW>
      <produto>1</produto>
      <tab>10</tab>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <produto>2</produto>
      <tab>10</tab>
    </ROW>
  </ROWS>
</registro>
```

escrevi uma classe:

```
public class registro
{
  public Header header { get; set; }
  public Parametros parametros { get; set;}
  public List<Row> ROWS { get; set;}
}

public class Row
{
  public string produto { get; set;}
  public string tab { get; set;}
}

public class Parametros
{
  public string consulta { get; set;}
}

public class Header
{
  public string codUsuario { get; set;}
  public string codLojista { get; set;}
}
```

Resumo é isso, mas ao carregar o xml na classe tenho o seguinte erro:

Unknow node: ROW

ja alterei de varias formas a estrutura da classe, usei atributos para setar o ElementName e nada.

EDIT: 
Carrego o XML na classe usando um recurso que utilizo para carregar outros documentos XML, inclusive de NF-e/CT-e/NFS-e

uso desta forma:

```
registro reg = new registro();
ReadXML<registro>(ref reg, xml);
```

método ReadXML:

```
public void ReadXML<T>(ref T AObject, string AXml)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AXml);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
        ms.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownAttribute);
        ser.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownElement);
        ser.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
        ser.UnreferencedObject += new UnreferencedObjectEventHandler(Serializer_UnreferencedObject);

        AObject = (T)ser.Deserialize(ms);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao serializar. Erro: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está fazendo o parse? Dê mais detalhes, está faltando código

Comment: editei e adicionei a maneira que carrego o xml para a classe (objeto)

Comment: Desculpa mas ainda ta faltando a classe Parametros e Header para darmos uma olhada. Se possível o print do erro tb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mapeamento do seu XML está incorreto. Para que o código funcione conforme o esperado, você precisa utilizar um wrapper que encapsula a lista.

## Classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="header")]
public class Header {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="codUsuario")]
    public string CodUsuario { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="codLojista")]
    public string CodLojista { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="parametros")]
public class Parametros {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="consulta")]
    public string Consulta { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="ROW")]
public class Row {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="produto")]
    public string Produto { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tab")]
    public string Tab { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="ROWS")]
public class Rows {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ROW")]
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="registro")]
public class Registro {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="parametros")]
    public Parametros Parametros { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ROWS")]
    public Rows Rows { get; set; }
}
```

## Capitalization Conventions

Não é indicado utilizar `Camel Case` para nome de classes e propriedades.

***Veja funcionando no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0szEd0)***

<sub>*Refêrencias:*</sub>

1. [Capitalization Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)
2. [Capitalization Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado! Minha interpretação estava totalmente equivocada, estava considerando o ROWS como List e na verdade ele não é um List, é apenas uma classe, e o ROW que é uma List, hora que vi seu exemplo deu vontade de bater com a cabeça na mesa kkk Obrigado